# Whats meaning of `Trunk` in `Getting setup with Trunk`?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

When I read this link: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs

There is a sentence:

> Getting setup with Trunk

I am not sure about the `Trunk` meaning here.

So, I query the dictionary, it may mean the tree's body, or some thing else.
But how about in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it sure sounds like [**a proper noun**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun) since the first letter of it is capitalized (proper nouns are the names of places, people, companies, products etc.). And upon closer inspection it indeed proves to be a proper noun (the name of a piece of software in this case): [**CocoaPods Trunk is an authentication and CocoaPods API service**](http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/getting-setup-with-trunk.html).

To spot a proper noun in English is an easy thing to do because they almost always begin with a capital letter (the only time I can think of when you would not capitalize the first letter is when you're doing it for stylization purposes) and typically, like 99% of the time, take no articles (*the White House*, for instance, is one of those exceptions). Here are some more examples:

> His real name is **John Smith**.
>   **Microsoft** is the world's largest seller of operating systems for personal computers.
>   **Paris** is the capital city of France.
>   One of the most popular programming languages of the last ten years has been **Python**.